# Max Daily Budget exceeded and Billing Status "Changing Daily Budget"

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

We've exceeded the Max Daily Budget for our app, but we can't increase the budget due to a serious flaw in Google's billing system.  Google App Engine and Google Wallet do not have very capable support for multiple sign-in.  As a result, I went to change the budget, but it used the wrong Google Wallet account (a different Google Account I was signed in as).  I had to go back and try again, but now our GAE app shows the following status:

**Billing Status: Changing Daily Budget**
Your account has been locked while we process your budget changes. If you were redirected to Google Checkout but did not complete the process, your settings will remain unchanged. (You will be able to make changes to your budget settings again once the outstanding payment is processed.)

Now I'm completely prevented from making any billing changes, our app is shut off (over quota), and I have NOTHING I can do to fix it.  This is a seriously fundamental flaw in App Engine's billing system and Google Wallet integration.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is there a workaround anyone is aware of?

Right now, our production app is completely down thanks to this issue.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated?

If you're from Google and you might be able to help on the backend, our app id is "nhldraftpik".

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: Have you tried talking to Google?

Comment: Ah. Talk to Google. If it were only that easy.  I've tried everything possible. Unfortunately, Google offers virtually no customer support. I've submitted my request about 6 different ways (all electronically). There's no phone number to call. You have to pay $500/mo. for "Premier Edition" in order to get real customer service.  As a lowly "Paid Edition" customer, I don't get any customer service.  Apparently the money I'm paying them isn't good enough to get real customer service.  I will see about getting SLA credits since this outage is caused 100% by a failure of their billing system.

Comment: I can see it works again... you can write down what did you do exactly to resolve that.. I'm guessing it was simply wait 1h or something until you will regain access to make billing modifications.. We had a similar thing in the past and when making changes, it takes some time to update or process or eventually canceling the request..

Comment: No, it's still not working for me.  It's happened one time to me before, and it took 24 hours for the issue to resolve itself.  I'm now at about 15 hours and counting...

Comment: @draftpik While the situation seems unfortunate and I agree that Google could have made things a bit more intuitive, there is also good evidence of user error on your part. The main thing you should do is continue to monitor your app and set/re-set quota before you run into similar issues. Especially since you said it happened to you before.

Comment: @Sologoub with all due respect, it's not user error at all.  I was monitoring my app.  I saw that we were approaching our max daily usage limit.  I went in to change the budget PRIOR to hitting the limit. The problem is that Google's billing system (Google Wallet) is incapable of properly handling Google's multiple sign-in support.  I did everything I was supposed to do to properly manage my account.  It should not be possible to be completely locked out of any control of your billing settings for a 24 hour period.  That is simply a fundamental flaw in Google App Engine's billing system.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you are connected to the wrong Google Wallet account.

If you have this issue again, please check that you are connected through the good Google Wallet.

If not, please click on logout, then login using the good account (without hitting the Back button).